# getting error "Some of the products below do not have all the required options" when i add product in cart in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am getting error "Some of the products below do not have all the required options" when i add product in cart. All are configurable products. why it is happen ?

[image]

Comment: What does `php` tag here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your product page. Find out your configurable product options (dropdowns). Maybe they are outside of product form. If you submit such form, selected values will not be send.

Comment: I have 2 options. For 1 options it is working fine but for second options it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, magento has some quirks, and sometimes finding them is a nightmare.  Here is a quick fix for your problem.... FYI, this will obliterate any required options you have PERSONALLY SET UP, so don't run this if you have a heavily configured set of required options on each product.

Execute this sql statement against your database.

```
update catalog_product_entity set required_options='0' where required_options='1';
```

Once you have run this, you should be able to go in and reconfigure your options and things will work as expected.